# Override virtual functions with overloading

Tags: c++, class, overloading, virtual, using

I have a base class, call it `Foo`, and a derived class, call it `Bar`. `Foo` defines a virtual function `doSomething`, with two overloads - see below:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething(std::string const & s)
    {
        printf("doSomething(std::string const &): %s\n", s.c_str());
    }

    virtual void doSomething(std::string const & s, int d)
    {
        printf("doSomething(std::string const &, int): %s %d\n", s.c_str(), d);
    }
};

class Bar
    : public Foo
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething(std::string const & s) override
    {
        printf("Bar: %s\n", s.c_str());
    }
};
```

Now I try and call both methods from an instantiation of the derived class Bar:

```
int main()
{
    Bar * b = new Bar();
    b->doSomething("string");
    b->doSomething("string", 78);
    delete b;
}
```

and I get an error for the second overload (the one that's not overridden in `Bar`). The one that's overriden is fine, but the other (that's still defined in the base class) I get an error

`error C2660: 'Bar::doSomething': function does not take 2 arguments`

If I remove the single override in `Bar`, so it just derives from `Foo` but doesn't override anything, the code in `main` compiles just fine. Same if I override both.

I'm sure I'm being dumb here, but this just doesn't seem to make sense. Can anyone help shed some light on this, and specifically how I can get that to work without either a) creating two function names, or b) always overriding both, or c) casting to the base class (which for my usage case would be a pain)? It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: A name in the derived class hides the same name in base class. Name lookup for `doSomething` finds `Bar::doSomething` and stops looking. To fix that, add this line somewhere in the definition of `Bar`: `using Foo::doSomething;`

Comment: Ha! Yes, that works! I need to make sure the `using` statement is accessible (so public), and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Or use `Foo * b = new Bar();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That should have been an answer, not a comment.